# Set methods between relationships in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 Entities - **Users** and **Projects**. The relationship between them looks like this:

```
// Acme/MyBundle/Entity/Project.php
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="projects")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $author;

public function setAuthor(\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User $author = null)
{
    $this->author = $author;

    return $this;
}
... other set/get methods...
```

and

```
// Acme/MyBundle/Entity/User.php
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $projects;

public function addProject(\Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Project $projects)
{
    $this->projects[] = $projects;

    return $this;
}
... other set/get methods...
```

The problem occurs when I am trying to create a project and assign the current user as author (and add the project in the user's field).

This is my createAction in the Project controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $entity = new Project();


    // THE PROBLEM PART
    $entity->setAuthor($user_id);
    $user = getUser($user_id); // get the user and attach the project
    $user->addProject($entity->getId());


    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

       return $this->redirect('homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Project:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

And obviously it returns me an error that says "Argument 1 passed to ... must be instance of ...".

Any ideas how to fix it?

*p.s. this is my first try to learn symfony2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can just give Doctrine (the default ORM of Symfony) the Object itself instead its id. Doctrine will figure out that it only has to save the id to the database.

So it would be:

```
$user = $this->getUser($user_id);
$entity->setAuthor($user);
```

You don't need to set it on the project as well, this is also taken care of by Doctrine.

Comment: Ha, I've tried almost everything except this, thanks @urbani :)